# Background image display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

I've got a simple problem of image display on my contact section. When you go to the section at the first load the background image isn't showing, when I'm re-loading it, it's showing but not like I want to. I want it to be like in this demo site : http://vandelaydesign.com/demos/single-page/  Here is my full website: http://lefestivaldufilmloupe.com/indexNOFLOAT

Here is my Css:

```
    #contact {
height: 1050px;
margin: auto;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
padding-top: 10%;
background: url(../images/train.jpg)no-repeat center center;
background-attachment: fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

My Html:

```
    <section id="contact">      
      <aside><h3><span>Vous voulez nous proposer un film loupé&thinsp;?
      N'hésitez pas à nous contacter&thinsp;: </span>
      <a href="mailto:lefestivaldufilmloupe@gmail.com">lefestivaldufilmloupe@gmail.com</a>
      </h3></aside> 
    </section>
```

What I am missing ?

I tried this two methods of preloading my image it's still not working well.
**First one** : image is displaying but not fullscreen on Firefox/Chrome.

```
     <script>
// better image preloading @ http://perishablepress.com
    function preloader() {
    if (document.getElementById) {
    document.getElementById("contact").style.background = "url(images/train.jpg)                 no-repeat center center";}
    }
    function addLoadEvent(func) {
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
    } else {
    window.onload = function() {
    if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
        }
        func();
    }
    }
    }
    addLoadEvent(preloader);
    </script>
```

Here full code: http://www.lefestivaldufilmloupe.com/indexPRELOAD1.html

**Second**: perfect on firefox, not displaying on chrome, and partially displaying on safari.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#contact").hide(); //on cache le contenu

    $("body").append('<div id="wait"><img src="../lefestivaldufilmloupe/images/loading.gif" alt="chargement..."/></div>')
    });
    $(window).load(function(){

    $("#wait").hide();

    $("#contact").fadeIn();

    });
    </script>
```

Here full code: http://www.lefestivaldufilmloupe.com/indexPRELOADJQUERY.html

The problem comes from my type animation. Without Textillate.js and all is dependencies it works well. 
I fix it like that: First, I add my contact section in jquery.sticky:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#header").sticky({topSpacing:10});
    $("#lignejaune").sticky({topSpacing:0});
    $("#contact").sticky({topSpacing:1050});
     });
    </script>
```

Then I add a z-index: -1; in my #contact css. The image is displaying correctly in Chrome/Safari, with or without preloading it doesn't change much.

EDIT: corrected html, preloading image, Fix.

Comment: Please format your code, it hurts to try to read unformatted code, so I am skipping this question, as interesting as it looks

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem may be broken html. Valid html can not have a "br" tag inside of a span. Try this html:

```
<section id="contact">
    <aside><h3><span>Vous voulez nous proposer un film loupé&thinsp;?
            N'hésitez pas à nous contacter&thinsp;: </span>
           <a href="mailto:lefestivaldufilmloupe@gmail.com">lefestivaldufilmloupe@gmail.com</a>
        </h3></aside> 
</section>
```

And add this CSS:

```
#contact span {
  display: block;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```

I'm getting inconsistent behavior with showing or not showing the image correctly, but fixing this will eliminate it as a factor in the problem, so that it will be easier to pin down what the problem really is.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly in Firefox now. I checked my html in W3C, there is no more error. It's still not showing well in Chrome/Safari, I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: The image is fairly large. I'm noticing that in Chrome it comes in partially, then on resize window, it appears fully. Have you tried pre-loading it?

Comment: Yes I tried two methods of pre-loading, it's still not working well. I edited my question.